# How to NSLog a bytebuffer ( NSData / const char* ) that includes zeros in the buffer stream?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, nslog, bytebuffer, pdf-parsing

I want to **NSLog** the content of a **PDF** that has compressed stream objects which include zeros ('**0**') in the middle of the stream.

Unfortunately the first occurrence of '**0**' in the first stream object terminates the output on the console...

Couldn't find anything on **SO** or in the cloud  at all.
Tried it in 4 different ways...

```
    NSString *pdfFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"myPDF" ofType: @"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

    ________________________________________________________________________
    //1
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    ________________________________________________________________________
    //2   
    NSString *myDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData
                                                     encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", myDataAsString);
    ________________________________________________________________________
    //3
    NSString *myPDFasString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                       encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@", myPDFasString);
    ________________________________________________________________________ 
    //4       
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                                   encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringFromFileAtURL);
```

OUTPUT on the console for all 4 of them: (of course -- it is always a null-terminated string in the backing-store)

```
    %PDF-1.1  
    %
    1 0 obj <<  
      /Type /Catalog  
      /Count 1  
      /Pages 6 0 R >>  
    endobj

    2 0 obj <<  
    %%/Type /Stream  
      /Filter /FlateDecode  
      /Length 12 >>  

    stream
    x+TT
```

Here the stream ends because of the '0' after 'x+TT' (which is the beginning of stream object)...

Anyone?

Comment: Show some relevant code in your question.

Comment: `myData` can't simply be converted to an `NSString` since `myData` isn't actually string data.

Comment: Yeah, you just get the NSData description... - That's not the point! The problem is not how to retrieve the string to be passed to NSLog. The problem is that the string has a '0' in the middle because it's just a string representation of some binary data which happens to have a '0' in the middle of the data-blip -> and this '0' terminates the stream as if it were (actually it is) the null-terminator. I need a 'String Format Specifier' that treats the whole blip as an entity and doesn't rely on a terminating zero!

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` when formatting a C-style string will stop at a null, as will anything else outputting a C-string.

There are multiple ways you can tackle your problem with simple code, this is only for debugging so no need to get fancy. Here are some pointers:

- `NSData` can give you a pointer to the bytes, `bytes`, and how many there are, `length`.
- The standard C library function `isprint` will tell you if a character is printable.
- The standard C library function `putchar` will output a single character to the console.
- If you want to produce some representation of the non-printables you might find `printf` useful.

If you get stuck ask another question including the code you've written.

HTH

Comment: Oh, come on guys - I don't wanna be rude - I know you are trying to help but you have to read my question more carefully!!! Can NSLog write anything to the console that has an occurrence of a '0' in the middle of the output-string (before the string-terminating '0' at the end)?

Comment: @mramosch - Apologies that wasn't clear, edited the answer.

Comment: **@CRD:** Thank you for clarifying - but that's exactly my point and question. Is there either with or without NSLog a chance to get a data-blip that includes a zero in its body - out to the console? Got any ideas on this?

Comment: @mramosch - Yes, write some code to do it, the functions mentioned in the answer are all you need.

Comment: I just can't believe it! 2015 and we should still mess around with this low-level stuff - as if I were the first who wanted to see a binary stream on the console - unbelievable... Thx anyhow, but still waiting for someone to come around and prove you wrong... ;-)))

Comment: @mramosch - Seriously? This is a few lines of custom code, just write it. A loop, a conditional, and you're done.